# Missing audio output device

Tags: 16.04, sound

I just deleted my old Ubuntu 14.04 and installed 16.04 and I'm having trouble finding one of my audio devices.

You see, I have an HDMI monitor and an onboard audio card. In my old Ubuntu, I used to have two options in the "Sound settings" (in fact more than two but the rest didn't do anything). Selecting the HDMI option would have resulted in the audio to be played by my monitor and there was this (something) Analog option which selecting that would lead to the audio to be played from my headphones (connected to the onboard audio card).

Now that I've installed Ubuntu 16.04, the analog option is missing from the Sound settings window and the audio is played only by my monitor (HDMI). The funny part is that my headset's mic (connected onboard audio card) is active as the input device. But the output device of the same exact audio card is not recognized.

Here are some info I've gathered:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And here's the screenshot of my sound setting's window:

[image]

Comment: I have the exact same issue in 18.04

Comment: @JonathanGood lucking fixing it. Unfortunately, I've moved to Kubuntu and I'm not facing that problem anymore. So I cannot help you fix it, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by changing the profiles of the output in Pulse Audio Volume Control `pavucontrol`
Each device also has it's own profile, and if that' set wrong it will make the device useless. Btw it said my device is "Unplugged" but that wasn't true.

[image]

Oddly if I changed in the Ubuntu sound properties after it would revert back to the wrong profile